# Uncertain about form with GET request using JavaScipt at spoonacular API

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ejs

I'm making a GET request to spoonacular, but I created a form so that the person can post their details and get menu items back.

So far, I've been having a lot of trouble getting results. I'm still new to RESTful API requests with JavaScript (more experience with Python), so I'm pretty certain the syntax is wrong.

I'm using EJS, so I have an index.ejs file.

Can anyone give me some feedback? If it helps, I wrote this in TypeScript.

This is the TypeScript code:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.get("/", (req, res) => { // This is the website itself, without any requests.
  res.render("index.ejs");
});

app.post('/food', async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

    interface SpoonacularSearchParams {
        query: string;
        number: number;
        apiKey: string;
    };

    try {
      // Make a request to Spoonacular API and get JSON data
      const response = await axios.get('https://api.spoonacular.com/food/menuItems/search', {
        params: {
          query: req.body.food,
          number: 10,
          apiKey: apiKey,
        } as SpoonacularSearchParams,
      });
  
      const result: string = response.data;

      // Pass the 'recipes' data to the EJS template
      res.render('index.ejs', { recipes: JSON.parse(result) });
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error('Failed to make request:', error.message);
      res.render('index.ejs', { error: error.message });
    }
});
```

And this is the index.ejs file:

```
  <form action="/food" method="POST" id="food">
    <label for="food">Search for food:</label>
    <input type="text" id="food" name="food" required>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>

  <% if (locals.recipes && locals.recipes.length > 0) { %>
    <ul>
        <% recipes.forEach(recipe => { %>
          <li>
            <img src="<%= recipe.image %>" alt="<%= recipe.title %>">
            <br>
            <a href="<%= recipe.image %>"><%= recipe.title %></a>
          </li>
        <% }); %>
      </ul>         
  <% } else { %>
    <p>No menu items found.</p>
  <% } %>
```

Thanks for the feedback!

I'm still learning, so I really do appreciate the guidance. This is a project that was offered with a different approach, and I thought an API request would be a lot easier and more efficient.

Comment: `I've been having a lot of trouble getting results` is not a problem statement we can help you with. You need to be specific, and you also need to learn how to debug.

Comment: @IanKemp - What I mean to say is that the webpage loads. That is fine. The TypeScript is fine, as is the EJS. But when I go and search, I immediately get "No menu items found." That continues to happen whatever I try to do.

Comment: Does `req.body.food` contain parsed data. Can you `console.log('food', req.body.food);` as the first statement inside your `app.post('/food',` route handler?

Comment: When I search for food, local host crashes with "Failed to load resource."